Динамическое уведомление UI об изменениях в WPF
Всем привет, активно изучаю WPF, а именно фреймворк Avalonia(MVVM), и тут возник такой вопрос. Как сделать динамическое обновление UI? Например:
У меня есть UserControl который содержит в себе DataGrid, сам DataGrid получает данные из БД, если например добавить новый элемент в БД, то в UI мы не увидим этот новый элемент, до тех пор пока не перезапустить приложение, т.е заново не проинициализировать конструкторы, которые подтягивают данные. Как сделать это более динамически чтобы приложение само знало когда обновлять данные в UI и т.д?
Понятно, что к DataGrid мы привязываем ObservableCollection, который уведомляет UI об изменениях, и тем самым у нас обновляется DataGrid и видны новые элементы. У меня вопрос именно как сделать так чтобы методы, которые выполняют запросы к БД вызывались тогда, когда нужно обновить данные. Вот пример кода:
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        CarsRental = new ObservableCollection<CarsRentalModel>();
        LoadCollectionCars();
        BtnSaveChangedCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(SaveChanges);
    }

    private void LoadCollectionCars()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (ApplicationContextDb db = new())
            {
                var cars = await db.CarsRentalModels.ToListAsync();

                foreach (var item in cars)
                {
                    CarsRental.Add(item);
                }
            }
        });
    }

Тут у меня есть конструктор TestViewModel в котором я вызываю метод LoadCollectionCars. Данный конструктор инициализируется при запуске приложения, получается, что метод вызывается один раз и подтягивает данные на момент инициализации конструктора. Как сделать так, чтобы метод сам знал, что данные нужно обновить?
Тут уже идут мои варианты как можно это сделать:

Наверное, самый убогий и неправильный способ - это создать бесконечный цикл в конструкторе и засунуть туда Task.Delay(time), после чего вызывать метод для обновления данных.
Самый простой и тупой способ - у меня в приложении, есть условно главное меню, в котором можно выбирать страницы для посещения так скажем. И вот при нажатии на кнопку для перехода на этот UserControl, можно просто вызывать метод, который будет идти в БД и возвращать данные. Хотя это даже за способ нельзя назвать, так как это не будет работать если пользователь уже находится на данной странице.
Самый наверное лучший способ из представленных - это просто сделать события и уведомлять подпищиков об изменениях, тем самым обновлять мой UI. Сделать это можно использовав SqlDependency, оно создаст событие, которое срабатывает при изменении данных в отслеживаемой таблице. Но я не совсем понимаю какие нюансы есть у данного способа и как правильно его реализовать для корректной работы, потому что ни разу этого не делал.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Задача базы - хранить данные и выдавать их по запросу, все. Всякие оповещения и прочее, это не ее ответственность. Далее, ваше приложение не должно напрямую общаться с базой, это не безопасно, ваша база вообще не должна смотреть наружу. Так что, если отвечать на ваш вопрос, то думаю уже поняли, что у вас должен быть посредник между клиентом и базой, который обрабатывает запросы, проверяет, делает что надо с ними, получает из базы нужное, ну и формирует ответ. Ну а уже посредник должен ваше приложение оповещать, любым удобным способом.

Добавляет данные в БД эта же программа? Или кто то другой может туда добавить данные и вам надо об этом узнать?

Detect changes with SqlDependency - простой способ начать. Думаю, понимаете, что прочесть желательно весь раздел Query Notifications (меню слева). Track data changes - более мощные средства. Вникать долго и усердно. PS: язык документации можно изменить на русский в левом нижнем углу.

@EvgeniyZ - а посредник как узнает, что данные в БД изменились? Т. е. возвращаемся к тому же вопросу.

@AlexanderPetrov Не совсем. Имея посредника, можно уже на нем отловить события добавления и изменения, по которым он уже будет отправлять клиентам нужные команды. Условно вызываем /api/add, данные проверяются, добавляются, если все успешно, событие, ну а в это время клиент сидит и слушает допустим через соккет команды от сервера. В любом случае, не задача базы оповещать (хоть некоторые это и умеют).

@EvgeniyZ Ну то есть, в итоге мне нужно реализовать посредника, который будет отправлять запрос в БД и отдавать результат приложению? А уже в самом посреднике можно реализовать SqlDependency? Так же, если не сложно, можете, пожалуйста, скинуть какую нибудь документацию по реализации этого самого посредника?

Посредником обычно делают сайт с REST API, на C# это ASP.NET. Далее, там реализуют нужный функционал, допустим добавление данных, это пусть будет POST запрос на site.ru/api/add, получение - GET на site.ru/api/{id}, ну и так далее... Сайт, когда видит эти правильно сформированные запросы, уже общается с базой, отправляя туда нужные запросы. То есть, ваш клиент (приложение авалония) ничего не знает про базу, он только взаимодействует с сайтом. Ну а обновления, как и писал выше, при условном /add вы вызываете механизм оповещения, на который подписан клиент. Таких механизмов нынче много.

Зачем Task.Run для и без того асинхронного метода? Вы выводите в пул потоков то, что туда выводить нет смысла, оно и так асинхронное. Ну и конечно же привязанную ObservableCollection вы не можете модифицировать из стороннего потока, это просто не будет работать.
